# PhoneGap application uses old version of my JS files

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, crosswalk

I'm developing a mobile application using PhoneGap for over a year and I just started to have a bizarre problem...

I'm editing a js file and then want to see the result on a real device, so I'm building (phonegap build android) and running (phonegap run android) to get the app installed on my device with the updated js files - but after the app starts, it uses the old js file.

I figured these js files must be cached somewhere, so I completely uninstalled the app from my device and then reinstalled it (phonegap run android) - but to my surprise I still got the old JS.

A few hints that may be relevant to this issue:

- The js file is loaded after the page completes loading on the webview (I use jQuery to insert the  tag into the  section)
- I do use CrossWalk and recently updated from 1.5 to 1.7.2. If I remove CrossWalk, reinstall the app, then add CrossWalk and then reinstall the app, it does get the updated JS files

Any help is appreciated!
Joseph.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this issue by removing the android platform and adding it back (phonegap platform rm android && phonegap platform add android)